# Firefox Float Misbehavior

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I have run into a float layout problem with a site that I am currently redeveloping - take a look at [here](http://countryguides.net/paul/).  The intended layout is

1. An empty padded area to the left (leftGap)
2. A vertical menu bar adjacent to it (menuBar)
3. The main page body (bodyBox)

Here is the relevant CSS

```
#leftGap {width: 200px;float: left;min-height: 1em;}
#menuBar {width: 250px;float: left;min-height: 1em;}
#bodyBox {width:**???**px;float:left;clear:right;min-height:1em;
          padding:0.5em;padding-left:8em;padding-right: 8em;}
```

I use a spot of JavaScript to resize the **bodyBox** at runtime to make best possible use of available screen width

```
function resizeBodyBox()
{
 var w = $('body').innerWidth() - $('#leftGap').width() - 
         $('#menuBar').width() - $.scrollBarWidth() - 25;
 //25 - a  "don't be greedy" insurance against unexpected behavior
 $('#bodyBox').css('width',w);
}
```

This works perfectly well on Chrome, Opera, IE7, 8, 9 & 10 (Yes! even IE).  However, in Firefox **bodyBox** insists on wrapping around and placing itself under **menuBar** as though there isn't "enough space" to accommodate the width I am assigning it (which is not the case, in any case).

I have played around with bodyBox in Firebug but to no avail.  There are a number of threads, here and on other forums, that talk about unusual float behavior in Firefox but nothing I have read appears to apply or help here.

I would much appreciate any help with identifying the underlying cause for this behavior. (I should mention that I use box-sizing:border-box so it is unlikely that the effect is down to margin/padding issues that I have overlooked).

Comment: That JavaScript really isn't helping anything. Getting rid of it, and removing the width on bodyBox from the css might fix your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

border-box seems to do the trick:

```
#bodyBox {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!  I had always believed that box-sizing was one of the few CSS3 attributes that was safe to use without a vendor prefix.  How wrong I was! - [http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).  Firefox requires it - even in its latest incarnation.  Thanks a lot!